# Block Outgoing SMS

Tags: android, sms

How can I block outgoing an SMS if it contains a filtered word according to a database? I can monitor that a sent message contains a filtered word but I am unable to block the SMS.

Comment: Off topic, unless you want to do that with code. In general however, this is a user setting and not something an application should perform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to Intercept incoming calls/sms to either block/unblock it?..Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406867/is-there-any-way-to-intercept-incoming-calls-sms-to-either-block-unblock-it-and)

Answer (score 1):

You can not stop default message sending application on your mobile to send sms. for this you have have to create your own sms box application and then you are able to add your customized feature to it.