# How to trigger events after ending all calls?

Tags: android

I am new in android.

- I want to **trigger incomming and outgoing calls**, and **code should be executed when any call( incomming and outgoing) started and ended**...
- I know that BroadcastReceiver is helpful for that. But can u give me the code/idea for that..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered many times in forum please check [Is there a way on Android to intercept incoming calls/SMSes to either block/unblock it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406867/is-there-any-way-to-intercept-incoming-calls-sms-to-either-block-unblock-it-an)

This might answer your question.