# How to delete SMS before save inbox

Tags: android

I have followed this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-sms-from-inbox-in-android-programmatically) . But using that, I'm not able to delete current receiving SMS. If I'm delete ALL message in in box. But currently receiving (BroadcastReceiver invoking SMS) not able to delete.

Is there any way to delete that message also.

Thank You,
Chandana

Comment: There is no "SMS inbox" that will work across all devices, or possibly even all versions of Android. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Comment: 0
 

@CommonsWare Thanks for You help. Using ContentProviders I have deleted SMS messages. but not able to delete SMS before Save.It want to delete after save it.

Comment: have a look to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175969/how-to-prevent-sms-going-to-inbox-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty late, but still if someone looking for this, the solution is to just abort the broadcast, it will stop saving the current sms in "inbox". just use `abortBroadcast();` it will stop the broadcast as well as prevent the sms from being saved..