# WhatsApp Android preventing SMS from going to the Inbox

Tags: android, android-broadcast, whatsapp

I'm interested in preventing an SMS from going to the inbox.

I read other questions/answers here on stackoverflow, like this:
[How to prevent SMS going to inbox in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175969/how-to-prevent-sms-going-to-inbox-in-android)

And there are several persons saying stuff like this:

> If you have an existing app which relies on aborting SMS message
>   broadcasts then you may want to consider the impact this change in
>   behaviour will have when your users upgrade to Android 4.4+.

So...
I´ve noticed that WhatsApp prevents the verification-code-SMS from going to the inbox. 
I´m talking about this activity:

[image: SMS verification code activity]

My question is: does the SMS popup in newer Android versions? isn´t prevented from going to the inbox in newer Android versions?

If it does popup and it does go to the inbox, I guess that they are using the same piece of code: `aboutBroadcast();` and I will stop concerning about this subject. But if it doesn´t popup and they do prevent the SMS from going to the inbox, I´ll ask: **how they do it??**

Comment: Have you got any solution to this?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Maye they were just rumours and u can actually prevent it (the sms going to inbox) in newer android versions

Comment: I also have seen some apps that can truly prevent receiving sms from going to inbox, as I have researched so far it can be done only by specifying port number in AndroidManifest.xml file. I am working on this and I hope to solve it.