# How to access sms inbox from javascript on android (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, android, sms, cordova

I just discovered PhoneGap and was wondering if there's a way to access the SMS inbox from Javascript with it. Or if there's another easy way to do it in an app created from a HTML/CSS/JS solution.

There's no info about SMS access in the phonegap docs, but maybe the inbox is avaliable as a url or a folder?

I would like to stick with phonegap so that the app would work on many devices, but an android only solution is satisfactory too.

Comment: hey naugtur, I see you haven't marked any of te answers as correct, and you must have solved it as its two years old now - so am wondering, how did you solve your problem in the end?

Comment: Well, I just gave up on the idea I had back then and I will accept an answer that works when it emerges. I'd post an answer if I had a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin for doing it with phonegap,

Take a look at [SMS reception plugin for Phonegap](https://github.com/Pyo25/Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin)

Comment: This is only for receiving the incoming smses but to access all smses which are there in inbox already, any plugin is not there.

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is not currently in PhoneGap though it might come in a future release. This is something that whole community would probably appreciate!

I think you will want to create a plugin to achieve this functionality for the moment. Some examples of plugins are here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins.

Here is an example of using an Android ContentProvider to interact with the SMS inbox [How to delete an SMS from the inbox in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-sms-from-inbox-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: That's bad news for me, as I have no intention of learning how to create native apps for all the platforms... Can I issue a feature request or comment an existing one somewhere?

Comment: I would try asking on the phonegap mailing list. Creating a plugin for phonegap does not involve that much native coding and is often similar between Android and BlackBerry at least.