# Triggering Intents remotely in Android

Tags: android, web-services

I am writing an Android app that talks to a server.  The server has information that is updated irregularly, and the app must be informed of each update.  My current solution is to have the app query the server at regular intervals to see if the information has been updated.

Is there any way to have the server initiate the interaction (say, only when the information is actually updated)?  I have heard about "Remote Intents" which simulate this behavior, but I have not been able to find any information on them.  Does anyone have any advice on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [Cloud To Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html).  This is designed to do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Is this the only technology that does this?

Answer (score 1):

You could have the server send out an SMS message, and the application checks for a certain pattern (perhaps starts with something known).  The data is extracted from the message and the notification is raised.

This question deals with how to analyze incoming messages:
[How to analyze incoming SMS on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637821/how-to-analyze-incoming-sms-on-android)