# Manipulate incoming SMS in Android

Tags: android, sms

How to manipulate certain incoming SMS messages in Android?
I want to change sender number before message will reach Inbox (so all text messages coming from a range of numbers wold be grouped into single conversation).

Can this be done from broadcast receiver of android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED intents?

Comment: Plz do some search before posting questions..Refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637821/how-to-analyze-incoming-sms-on-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it. What you get through `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`, the data is a copy, so even if you change it wont be changed for other Recievers. You can block it from going to other Broadcasts, but not change it and rebroadcast

What you could do is manipulate using contentProvider of SMS . You will need WRITE_SMS permission

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify incoming messages in "stealth mode" and you cannot replace broadcast with your fake message without rooting and platform modifications. You can try to play with SMS using content provider but you need WRITE_SMS permission so your intentions would be clear to many.

Comment: Sorry, but I am writing a legitimate application and users will be fully aware of what it will be doing. There is a mobile operator in my country that has email-to-sms service which sends each sms from a different from number (but always starting with the same prefix), each new email starts a new conversation in Messaging application - my application will be a workaround for this.