# any listener for delete sms in android

Tags: android, sms

in my application i would like to get sms information while is deleting from inbox by user. For this is there any listener or else? any one of you plz help me. is there any aletrnate....
ThanQ.

Comment: **Possible Duplicate of [Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox)**

Comment: my requirement is while deleting any SMS from inbox i need to get that SMS.

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically

Comment: @VenkaReddy hi have you found any solution for this.Please do share as I am stucked in same situaltion

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a BroadcastReciever to listen for the "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" intent. [This page](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) has a nice example of how to get it set up.

Edit:
I don't think(But I am not absolutely sure) there is any way to get notified when a message is about to get deleted. Why does your application need access to the users SMS messages that they are deleting?

Comment: my requirement is while deleting any SMS from inbox i need to get that SMS.