# Listen for sms delete android

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a listener for when user deletes sms from the inbox.

[any listener for delete sms in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025372/any-listener-for-delete-sms-in-android)
My question is duplicate but the thread hasn't an answer.

Comment: It's not possible. I can't imagine what is your goal but you need to find another way to do what you want.

Comment: you can have 2 variable. OldCount and NewCount. Then do NewCount - OldCount you will get the deleted sms count.

Comment: Dear Ajay GU, I want to get the deleted one's text, count may not be necessary. is there a way to know which one is deleted?

Comment: @MTP1376 Nope. Just store copies of SMS with text and checking as I wrote.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case we need to check it every 5min (for example) which takes memory :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i see many sms manager apps doing that without any background process,  if you delete one sms in one of them , the others immediately remove that sms too, i know that we can use `ContentObserver` but i don’t think this is the right way

in your activity :

```
   public static void InitializeObserver(Context c) {
    try {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = c.getContentResolver();
        Handler mSmsObserverHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        SmsObserver mSmsObserver = new SmsObserver(mSmsObserverHandler, c);
        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), true, mSmsObserver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

observer class :

```
public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {
SharedPreferences trackMeData;
private Context c;

public SmsObserver(Handler handler, final Context c) {
    super(handler);
    trackMeData = c.getSharedPreferences("LockedSIM", 0);
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);

}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no broadcast intent for this. You can implement your own checker by loading SMS count and ids and compare this result with the previous one time-by-time. It looks not good and can drain battery if you will make this checking too frequently, but I think it's only one way to resolve problem.