# Android: Listen for incomming sms when GoSMSPro installed

Tags: java, android, sms

Here is my code:

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingSms"     android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483648">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My app work fine when GoSMSPro is not installed.I install my app fisrt then install GoSMSPro but still can not receive sms.

I have another question and it is: how BeeTalk can receive registration sms when even GoSMSPro is installed?

Comment: are you testing it in kitkat?

Comment: no. but Beetalk can receive sms in all version of android

Comment: From what I can tell, BeeTalk doesn't have the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission, but it does have the `READ_SMS` permission, so I would guess that it starts a `ContentObserver` on the SMS inbox before doing the registration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28384342/3138818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android: Listen for incomming sms when GoSMSPro installed

Some applications register SMS BroadcastReceiver with highest priority so those application receive callback of received SMS first and halt this receiver so other application which also register this won't receive callback.

Alternate option , you can use `ContentObserver` that receive callback when there is any message received/deleted etc.