# IllegalArgument exception Unknown Url

Tags: android, sms

I get an Illegal argument exception : Unknown url for the following code wen i try and access content://sms/ at the delete part

```
package com.messageHider;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class smsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("context://sms/inbox");
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
         SmsMessage[]message=null;
         String number="";
         String body="";
         if(bundle!=null)
         {
            Object[]pdus=(Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            message=new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for(int counter=0;counter<message.length;counter++)
            {
                message[counter]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[counter]);
                number=message[counter].getDisplayOriginatingAddress().toString();
                body=message[counter].getMessageBody().toString();
            }
         }
        //Compare
         dbConnection conn=new dbConnection(context);
         SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor=db.query(dbConnection.TABLE_CONTACTS,null,dbConnection.CONTACT+"=?",new String[]{number},null,null,null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         int count=cursor.getCount();

        if(count>0)
         {
            int rows=context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"+number),null,null);
            if(rows>0)
            {
                   Toast.makeText(context,"Messagehidden",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         }
    }

}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Might want to fix up your formatting with your code there. I would help you but I can't edit (not enough reputation.)

Comment: Check this question and the answers in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically

Comment: @JackMc I think you can propose edits, they just won't go live until someone with enough rep accepts them.

Comment: @Tim Ah, thanks! I'm still a newbie to the site :).

Answer (score 1):

`Uri uri=Uri.parse("context://sms/inbox");`

It should be content scheme
 `Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");`

If it is about second Uri try to use `ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), number)` to compose Uri http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html

**UPDATE according comments below**
To have sms cursor filtered by phone number you should set WHERE string

```
getContentResolver().delete(
            Uri.parse("content://sms"),
            "address LIKE '%" + phoneNumber + "'",
            null);
```

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by "it should be content scheme". But I agree as in: the first (non-error) call it does use "context" instead of content, so I guess the code part of your answer is right :). Maybe expand a little bit on what you mean there?

Comment: Do u mean context or content coz in ur answer u have context://sms/inbox

Comment: Is he using that Uri anywhere?

Comment: Dont mind the Uri at the top, check out the one at the bottom wen deleting

Comment: number is not exactly the id in the sms content provider table but it is the address from where the message came from

Comment: @John I updated the answer. Now I've got what are you asking for.