# IIlegalArgument Exception ,unknown URL error in custom content provider

Tags: android

I am learning content provider with example.

My logcat shows **"IIlegalArgument Exception ,unknown URL"**.

> CONTENT URI = "content://com.example.DetailProvider/personaldetail"

where

```
com.example - packagename
DetailProvider - ContentProvider
class name      personaldetail - Tablename
```

Is the URI declared correctly ?

Comment: Try to escape the slashes with backslashes. ie: content://com will become "content:\/\/com"

Comment: yeahi tried it......but still same exception

Comment: Somehow your uri is wronk, this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076674/illegalargument-exception-unknown-url