# What is the correct CONTENT_URI for the SMS thread table?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm attempting to query the SMS thread table, but I don't seem to use the correct URI.

Querying the URI "content://sms/conversations" gives me the columns:

> [thread_id, msg_count, snippet]

Querying the URI "content://mms-sms/conversations" gives me the columns:

> [body, person, sub, subject, retr_st, type, date, ct_cls, sub_cs,
>   _id, read, ct_l, tr_id, st, msg_box, thread_id, reply_path_present,
>   m_cls, read_status, ct_t, status, retr_txt_cs, d_rpt, error_code,
>   m_id, m_type, v, exp, pri, service_center, address, rr, rpt_a,
>   resp_txt, locked, resp_st, m_size]

I'm looking for the URI that gives the values from the Threads table in android/provider/Telephony.java - data, recipient_ids, message_count, read, etc...

Thanks

Comment: I think this thread can help to answer this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035970/i-want-to-fetch-and-view-sms-conversations

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012287/how-to-read-mms-data-in-android

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
```

you can get what you want like this

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

    // List required columns
    String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "body" };

    // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    // Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, reqCols, "address = '" + number + "'", null, null);

    // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.single_conversation_view, cursor, new String[] {"body" }, new int[] {  R.id.tv_single_conversation_message }, 1);

    lv_single_conversation.setAdapter(adapter);
```

hope it will help you