# fetch all conversation sms of specific number using content provider query

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I am creating one application which displays all Inbox sms messages. On the list of sms messages, there is a button to read all that number's conversation with me.

It is done by fetching the intent object and comparing that object to a query of records address like this function..`

```
public void readConversation() {
    try {

        StringBuilder smsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(SMS_URI_ALL), null,
                null, null, "date ASC");
        int smsEntriesCount = cur.getCount();

        Log.d("smsEntriesCount", "" + smsEntriesCount);

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                data = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String smsAdress = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                String smsbody = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                String smsid = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")).toString();
                String smsdate = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString();
                String smstype = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString();
                String smsStatus = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status")).toString();
                String smsReadUnread = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("read")).toString();

                String contactnamelist = getContactDisplayNameByNumber(smsAdress);

                if (smsAdress.equalsIgnoreCase(straddress.trim())) {
                    data.put("_id", smsid);
                    data.put("address", contactnamelist);
                    data.put("body", smsbody);
                    data.put("date", smsdate);
                    data.put("type", smstype);
                    data.put("status", smsStatus);
                    data.put("ReadUnread", smsReadUnread);
                    NumberList123.add(data);

                    Log.d("Conversation id", smsid);
                    Log.d("Conversation Address", smsAdress);
                    Log.d("Conversation body", smsbody);
                    Log.d("Conversation date", smsdate);
                    Log.d("Conversation type", smstype);
                    Log.d("Conversation status", smsStatus);
                    Log.d("Conversation Read(1)-Unread(0)", smsReadUnread);

                }
            } while (cur.moveToNext());

        }
        convolistnumber = new application();
        convolistnumber.setListConvo(NumberList123);

        Log.d(Tag, " Arraylist size " + NumberList123.size());
        Log.d(Tag, "Convo List" + convolistnumber.getConvoList().size());



        if (!cur.isClosed()) {
            cur.close();
            cur = null;

        } else {
            smsBuilder.append("no result!");
        } 

    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`

By using this function i got all conversation of that number which is "straddress"  coming from main activity of button click but it gets more time becoz i search all sms address to straddress number and it takes much time...so is any solution if i check that number in query thats mean this function run quick...

I am also trying to check address in cursor but it results only sent sms of recipient and i want all sent and inbox sms that means conversation..

thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14721990/646806

Comment: hey robinhood thaks for replying..but i used same and its working but my issue is if phone have 500 sms then it checks all 500 sms addresses and then given me output and it takes much time..i want to decrease time to load..