# Get full conversation with Android query

Tags: android, android-cursor, displayobject, android-query

I would like to get all messages from one contact. I have the contact ID `_id`, so I've already do something like this :

```
private void displayMessages() {
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();


    try {
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations"), new String[]{"*"}, this.contID + "= _id" , null, null); //contID is the unique ID for one contact in our android.
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            System.out.println("Body : " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("ERROR");
    }
```

I've asked something like

```
SELECT * FROM content://mms-sms/conversations WHERE _id = contID
```

As you can see, in my query, I ask system for messages from one contact (user id that I know)  But I can just display the last message **body**. So I think it exists others query to get all messages from one user ?

Any ideas ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946262/read-inbox-messages-of-a-particular-number-and-display-them-in-an-activity  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721772/get-sms-of-specific-phone-number

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that `_id` in this case is the id of the contact you are sending sms/mms to but rather the thread's id. The column you probably want to use for your query clause is [RECIPIENT_IDS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.ThreadsColumns.html#RECIPIENT_IDS). For debugging purpose try without the where clause and dump the cursor to analyze the results

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations"), new String[]{"*"}, null , null, null);
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answer too late, but I've found a solution.

Here is my code :

```
private void displayMessages() {
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    boolean isMe;

    try {
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, this.cont.getThread_ID() + " = thread_id" , null, "date ASC");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            //if it's a received message :
            if ((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("person")) != null)) {
                isMe = false;
            }
            else {
                //it's a message sent by me.
                isMe = true;
            }

            date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
            System.out.println("Number: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            System.out.println("Body : " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body") + "\n");
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
```

Thanks to "conent://sms" table, I can get all sms !
So I've used *thread_id* to display all messages, and thanks to the *person* column, I can know if the message was sent by me or my contact.