# Get clean SMS conversation list and SMS

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to get the list of sms conversation and all of the SMS into them like this structure : (That's a conversation structure).

```
[
    "names":[
        "Antoine Duval",
        "Mike Tyson",
        "Marge Simpson"
    ],
    "numbers":[
        "+33 7 00 00 00 00",
        "+33 7 11 11 11 11",
        "+33 7 22 22 22 22"
    ]
    "last_date":"a date",
    "last-message":"a message",
    "sms"[
        [
            "text":"a message",
            "date":"a date",
            "number":"+33 7 00 00 00 00"
        ],
        [
            "text":"a message",
            "date":"a date",
            "number":"+33 7 00 00 00 00"
        ],
        [
            "text":"a message",
            "date":"a date",
            "number":"+33 7 00 00 00 00"
        ],
        (other messages in this conversation)...
    ]
    (other conversations)...
]
```

I never did it again so I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035970/i-want-to-fetch-and-view-sms-conversations) link.
I'ts giving me messages I received, not what I sended :'( and it just give me a list of message. It's not my clean structure :P
And the final problem is that's using "startManagingCursor" and it's deprecated, I don't find how to replace it :)

Maybe i'll have to list all conversation first, but i don't find how to get the conversations list :/

Comment: Change `"content://sms/inbox"` to `"content://sms"` to get all messages, if that's what you want. And just drop the `startManagingCursor()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Change "content://sms/inbox" to "content://sms" to get all messages, if that's what you want. And just drop the startManagingCursor() call." -> [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)