# Sent SMS by my application shown in default android application

Tags: android, sms

I am developing an android application in which my application send some message which have some specific codes and these codes used to operate my device. And my device is not phone it's an another custom hardware device (Developed an another hardware which is used to control other hardware such as AC/Cooler etc).

Now problem is that whenever my application send any SMS this is shown in SMS default application (O.S 5.0 or greater). While in my phone O.S. 4.2 these sent SMS not shown. And that's what I want. These specific codes should not shown to any one.

I know this is some API change android have done in SDK but there is any solution to overcome from this problem.

Comment: "my application send some message which have some specific codes and these codes used to operate my device" -- your device has a security flaw, then. SMS is not suitable as a control channel, as SMS messages can be spoofed by attackers.

Comment: actually device have no user interaction except manual off/on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only solution for this problem can be *"Delete the sms from Sent folder/table of SMS database."*

But on or after Android 4.0, Deletion from SMS database is not allowed by public apps. [SMS deletion not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29004539/519718)