# android delete message not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I would like to delete message when message arrives, I have setup broadcast listener, following is code sample:

```
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/");
    Cursor cur = c.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) 
    {


           for(int i = 0 ; i <uptoallmessage_n;i++)
           {


               if(matchednumber)
               {
                   long s = cur.getLong(1);
                   String str = "content://sms/conversations/" + s;
                   Log.e("msg", str);

                   try 
                   {
                       c.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(str), null, null);
                   } catch (Exception e) 
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }

    }
```

following permission i have setup

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Following uri i am getting in logcat

```
  07-16 18:14:26.069: E/msg(25477): content://sms/conversations/679
  07-16 18:14:26.072: E/msg(25477): content://sms/conversations/679
  07-16 18:14:26.076: E/msg(25477): content://sms/conversations/679
  07-16 18:14:26.079: E/msg(25477): content://sms/conversations/679
  07-16 18:14:26.082: E/msg(25477): content://sms/conversations/679
  07-16 18:14:26.084: E/msg(25477): content://sms/conversations/679
  07-16 18:14:26.086: E/msg(25477): content://sms/conversations/679
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programatically

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how can I make my app as default app or is there any other way to delete message ?

Comment: Thanks a lot I have read complete article and found all details, thanks

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept your answer. That will help others who have the same problem and will also remove this question from the list of unanswered questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have added answer and marked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is working fine before Android 4.4, As per google policy only default application can delete message. If you wish to make your apps default then you need to develop complete sms application and can make it default as per google documentations.