# how to cancel/prevent the propagation of default sms app in marshmallow

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i'm working on a little project which receive and show Message only by specific number,and don't show in inbox, is there is any method to prevent or cancel the default sms app?thanks in advance i'm attaching my code of Broadcasting and Manifest

```
 public class reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
       public String senderNumer=null;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle!=null)
            {
                Object[] pdus= (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
               // String senderNumer=null;
                for (int i=0;i<pdus.length; i++)
                {
                   SmsMessage sms=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                     senderNumer=sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                    String message=sms.getDisplayMessageBody();
                }
    if (senderNumer.equals("+92*******") || senderNumer.equals("03*******"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context,senderNumer+ "Message Recieved By Special Num",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    Intent actionIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    actionIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    actionIntent.putExtra("msg", senderNumer);
                    context.startActivity(actionIntent);
                    abortBroadcast();
                }
            }
```

Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".reciever" class=".reciever">
              <intent-filter android:priority="100000000" >
                 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
             </intent-filter>

         </receiver>
    </application>
```

Comment: you can something like delete SMS from the device storage after you know it is your SMS.

Comment: but how can i delete Desired/Specific SMS from storage? but if i delete from storage then it will also disappear from my own app?

Comment: if you save it separately, then it won't disappear from your app.

Comment: To delete SMS simply search for `android delete sms programmatically`

Comment: hmm thanks, after searching i'll be here

Comment: i guess you can not delete the sms storage unless your app is the default sms app.

Comment: @7383 so it is possible that first i make it default and then store sms in my own app DB and then i can delete sms from main DB and then show it?

Comment: Only the user can set the default messaging app. You cannot do it yourself programmatically. There really is no way to block incoming messages in Marshmallow unless the user has chosen your app to be the default.

Comment: @MikeM. So its clear without default app we can't delete or hide messages from main DB, will u please provide some links regarding making default app and how to delete sms ?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30133663, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8614211