# Delete sms from another activity Android

Tags: android

I access all sms using ("content://sms/inbox") in my custom list view currently i am getting address body and _id now i want to delete selected sms from another activity please guide me i am beginner in andorid 
this is my Mainactivity but i want to delete seleted sms from another activity

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor !=null  && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
        //    name = getContactName(address);
             tid=             cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
             body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
          if(name==null) {

                list.add(new mybean("" + address, "" + body,""+tid));

            }

            else{
                list.add(new mybean("" + name, "" + body,""+tid));
            }
            my =new  myadapter(this,list);
            lv.setAdapter(my);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }



        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);

                intent.putExtra("delete",list.get(pos).getDel());
                intent.putExtra("sms",list.get(pos).getNumber());
                intent.putExtra("smsmsg",list.get(pos).getMsg());


                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Since KitKat (4.4), your app cannot delete SMS from the Provider unless it is the current default messaging app.

Comment: yes i understand the logic now Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quide to how to delete sms 
[Deleting Android SMS programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programmatically/8851644#8851644)
For kitkat 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html
First you should choose your app as default sms app then you can delete or remove sms from there..
You can also refer to this post
[How to delete an SMS from the inbox in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically)
here is the tutorial for deleting sms programmatically 
http://wisdomitsol.com/blog/android/sms/programmatically-delete-sms-in-android
i hope you find these post helpful if any problem you can comment here.

1.First Add permission in manifest

2. write the method

```
public boolean deleteSms(String smsId) {
    boolean isSmsDeleted = false;
    try {
        mActivity.getContentResolver().delete(
                Uri.parse("content://sms/" + smsId), null, null);
        isSmsDeleted = true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        isSmsDeleted = false;
    }
    return isSmsDeleted;
}
```

you can now delete sms byIds

You can also try this code

```
try {
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
            uriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
                    "date", "body" }, "read=0", null, null);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            long id = c.getLong(0);
            long threadId = c.getLong(1);
            String address = c.getString(2);
            String body = c.getString(5);
            String date = c.getString(3);
            Log.e("log>>>",
                    "0--->" + c.getString(0) + "1---->" + c.getString(1)
                            + "2---->" + c.getString(2) + "3--->"
                            + c.getString(3) + "4----->" + c.getString(4)
                            + "5---->" + c.getString(5));
            Log.e("log>>>", "date" + c.getString(0));

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("read", true);
            getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),
                    values, "_id=" + id, null);

            if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                context.getContentResolver().delete(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?",
                        new String[] { c.getString(4) });
                Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success.........");
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log>>>", e.toString());
}
```