# delete recently getting sms programatically android in pie devices

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programmatically) to try delete recent sms. This code works fine and it shows sms deleted successfully in logcat but still not deleted from phone.

I am using this code when I am getting otp from broadcastreciever after that I want to delete my otp sms.

Help me I donot know to achieve that.

Comment: As per your reference link, have you tried placing delay while **deleting SMS**.

Comment: Since KitKat (4.4), you cannot delete SMS messages unless your app is the default messaging app. Is your app the default? I wouldn't think so, because then it would be responsible for saving the incoming SMS messages, which you could just not do for your OTP messages.

Comment: @MikeM. no bro I am just want to delete from any app

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, you can't. Only the default SMS app has write access to the SMS Provider. It's been like that for many years, now.

Comment: @MikeM. can you help me on my one more question. if you want I will share link with you.

Comment: I can take a look. No guarantees, though.