# Delete sent sms from sent box not working as inbox

Tags: android, smsmanager

```
public void deleteSMS(Context context, String message, String number) {
    try {
        mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS from sent");
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address",
                "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);

                if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                    mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mLogger.logError("Could not delete SMS from sent: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

i want to delete sent message but not able to delete sent sms. But sent sms are not deleting so please check the code and tell me where i am doing a mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting Android SMS programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programmatically)

Comment: I have done exactly like this what not working, i don't know so i have posted here

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851644/8762338 check if it helps

Comment: @Astha i Also Tried this in my code but not deleting sms