# How to delete all sms from inbox programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I am working on an application in which I want to delete all SMS from inbox.
For that I have used the following code.

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null); 
int id = c.getInt(0);
int thread_id = c.getInt(1); //get the thread_id
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + thread_id),null,null);
```

This code does not work.
Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delete uri is `"content://sms/" + id;`

```
Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
int count = 0;
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(inboxUri , null, null, null, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    try {
        // Delete the SMS
        String pid = c.getString(0); // Get id;
        String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
        count = context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri),
                null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
return count;
```

Comment: this is for single messge or a converstion?

Comment: Would this also remove all MMS messages?

Comment: this will all sms from inbox

Answer (score 1):

```
//delete all call logs
Uri callLog = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
int rs1 = getContentResolver().delete(callLog, null, null);

//delete all sms
Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");       
int rs2 = getContentResolver().delete(inboxUri, Sms._ID + "!=?", new String[]{"0"});
```