# Broadcast Receiver for sms - how to block/delete sms before it is read by default messaging app

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I aim to make an app that would store sms messages with certain words contained in an sms, and stop it from reaching the default messaging app. I realize that I need to place a broadcast receiver for sms messages in my app, but how do I ensure that If a message contains a KEYWORD, the message gets deleted immediately and becomes unaccessible to any other messaging app? I am stuck here, so any help is appreciated. Thank you

Regards,

Farhan

Comment: You might want to upvote and accept the answer. You stats show that you haven't accepted answers on any of your questions, that's not encouraging. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [How to delete an SMS from the inbox in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically) and [Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199). Before deleting it, apply logic to search the message for your KEYWORD and then delete only those specific messages.