# How can I delete ALL messages in the SMS inbox in Android?

Tags: android

I wanna delete ALL the messages in my Messaging with just one click on the button. But I already tried the coding below, it is not working... Can someone just help me to achieve this? Thanks...

```
public class DeleteSMSActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button press;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    press = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    press.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view){

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = cr.query(inboxUri , null, null, null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        // Delete the SMS
        String pid = c.getString(0); // Get id;
        String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
        cr.delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
    }
}
}
```

What should I add in Manifest? Having force close when testing with my Galaxy Tab 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try deleting with `_id` :

```
Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null,null);
try {
      while (c.moveToNext()) {
         int id = c.getInt(0);
         getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
      }

    }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e(this.toString(),"Error deleting sms",e);
    }finally {
      c.close();
    }
```

Comment: @user1782267 Added `catch` block.

Comment: It works!!! I just forgot to put READ_SMS and WRITE_SMS permissions in manifest... Thanks for the help...

Comment: where can i get the id for a number? @S.D.

Answer (score 0):

The delete uri is **"content://sms/" + id;**

```
Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
int count = 0;
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(inboxUri , null, null, null, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    try {
        // Delete the SMS
        String pid = c.getString(0); // Get id;
        String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
        count = context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri),
                null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
return count;
```

you can Also Refere [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically) & [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox) for More Detail Information About this topic. 
Hope it Will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

for Deleting SMS from inbox you need uses permission declared in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

now you will be able to delete your inbox sms and now you wont get the force close your emulator

Answer (score 0):

Today I found the way to delete all messages without loop, just by query.

```
mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null);
```

Follow this link for more detail
http://www.wisdomitsol.com/blog/android/sms/programmatically-delete-all-messages-in-android