# Hide SMSs sent using SMSManager Android

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I'm using **SMSManager**  to send and receive **Multipart Text Message** `sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(strPhone,null,messageParts,sentPendingIntents,deliveredPendingIntents);`

but what i see that on some devices the `SMSs` sent are not shown like on `Huawei` (6.0) device but are shown on other devices like `Samsung` (5.1.1), how i can hide the `SMSs` sent on all the devices (4.4.+)?

Comment: you cannot hide SMS messages. You can delete them, but only if your app is the default SMS app

Comment: but why i can't see the SMS sent on my Huawei device ? and i can see it on Samsung device ? @TimCastelijns

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically?lq=1) might be useful

Comment: that is useful for the Android 4.2..- @Signo

Comment: @nouha Yes but it was to point out that after 4.4 this is the default behaviour for `SMSManager`. You can't change that unless you register your app as default SMS app

Comment: i see, but why i can't see the SMS sent on my Huawei device and i can see it on Samsung device, that's why i'm searching for a solution.. anyway thanks @Signo

Comment: @nouha No problem! For the SMS not showing up, have you checked which app is set as default SMS app in your Huawei device? If it's the default one then please add to the question the full code for the message creation/sending.